# Getting unknown child div from parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".inventory-notes").bind("click", function() {
    if($(this).text().length > 0) {
        alert($(this).text());
        alert($(this).closest(".inventory-notes").children().text());
    }
});
</script>
```

example table

```
<table id="inventory" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Usage</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="items">
            <td>Hatchet</td>
            <td>24,000 Gold</td>
            <td>Woodcutting</td>
            <td><div class="inventory-notes"><div id="299"><img src="addnotes.png"></div></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the value 299 from the child div of `inventory-notes`? The table really contains at least 1,000 rows of items each containing a random ID.

I am using jQuery 1.6.2 so I cannot use the `.on() function.`

Comment: That `id` value is illegal. They cannot start with numbers. This may cause problems trying to access it.

Comment: oh wow, I forgot about that... I had the same problem last week. I'll try a prefix. Thank you Jon.

Comment: Also, the JavaScript makes no sense. Finding the closest `.inventory-notes` to an `.inventory-notes`? Working on the text nodes? eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery 1.6.2, I'd use `.delegate`:

```
$("#inventory").delegate(".inventory-notes", "click", function(){
    var id = $(this).find("div").prop("id");
});
```

Since you're going to have 1,000+ rows, you don't want to bind the event to the actual rows, resulting in 1,000+ handlers.

Comment: Wow this is impressive. Thank you very much!